# How to find 0 in an integer array of size 100 ,having 99 elements as 1 and only one element 0 in most efficient way

Tags: arrays, integer

I need to find the position( or index ) say i of an integer array A of size 100, such that A[i]=0. 99 elements of array A  are 1 and only one element is 0. I want the most efficient way solving this problem.(So no one by one element comparison).

Comment: no ...just a question asked in an interview

Answer (score 5):

Others have already answered the fundamental question - you will have to check all entries, or at least, up until the point where you find the zero. This would be a worst case of 99 comparisons. (Because if the first 99 are ones then you already know that the last entry must be the zero, so you don't need to check it)

The possible flaw in these answers is the assumption that you can *only check one entry at a time*.

In reality we would probably use direct memory access to compare several integers at once. (e.g. if your "integer" is 32 bits, then processors with SIMD instructions could compare 128 bits at once to see if any entry in a group of 4 values contains the zero - this would make your brute force scan just under 4 times faster. Obviously the smaller the integer, the more entries you could compare at once).

But that isn't the optimal solution. If you can dictate the *storage* of these values, then you could store the entire "array" as binary bits (0/1 values) in just 100 bits (the easiest would be to use two 64-bit integers (128 bits) and fill the spare 28 bits with 1's) and then you could do a "binary chop" to find the data.

Essentially a "binary chop" works by chopping the data in half. One half will be all 1's, and the other half will have the zero in it. So a single comparison allows you to reject half of the values at once. (You can do a single comparison because half of your array will fit into a 64-bit long, so you can just compare it to 0xffffffffffffffff to see if it is all 1's). You then repeat on the half that contains the zero, chopping it in two again and determining which half holds the zero... and so on. This will always find the zero value in 7 comparisons - much better than comparing all 100 elements individually.

This could be further optimised because once you get down to the level of one or two bytes you could simply look up the byte/word value in a precalculated look-up table to tell you which bit is the zero. This would bring the algorithm down to 4 comparisons and one look-up (in a 64kB table), or 5 comparisons and one look-up (in a 256-byte table).

So we're down to about 5 operations in the worst case.

But if you could dictate the storage of the array, you could just "store" the array by noting down the index of the zero entry. There is no need at all to store all the individual values. This would only take 1 byte of memory to store the state, and this byte would already contain the answer, giving you a cost of just 1 operation (reading the stored value).

Comment: adi: mark this answer as the solution if it helped you. This helps others to find it more easily.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it better then linear scan - unless the data is sorted or you have some extra data on it. At the very least you need to read all data, since you have no clue where this 0 is hiding.

If it is [sorted] - just access the relevant [minimum] location.

Answer (score 2):

Something tells me that the expected answer is "compare pairs":

```
while (a[i] == a[i+1]) i += 2;
```

Although it looks better that the obvious approach, it's still O(n),

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of it as you insert to build the array. Then just access the stored value directly. O(1) with a very small set of constants.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine 100 sea shells, under one is a pearl. There is no more information.

There is really no way to find it faster than trying to turn them all over. The computer can't do any better with the same knowledge. In other words, a linear scan is the best you can do unless you save the position of the zero earlier in the process and just use that.

Answer (score 0):

More trivia than anything else, but if you happen to have a quantum computer this can be done faster than linear.

[Grover's algortithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm)